# What is [loop0] process for?

Tags: docker, centos, device-mapper

I'm running apache in a docker container on a CentOS 7 machine with devicemapper (on a dedicated volume group not on loopback file).

After a few requests, system load dramatically increase even up to 20. Since the cpu load is reasonably low, i traced down the I/O activity with *iotop -a* and discovered that while the container is running the process [loop0] does a lot of reading from disk.

I googled a bit but i can't still figure out what is [loop0] for. Can someone give me a clue?
Can a process running inside a docker container, cause [loop0] to go nuts?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are using the default loopback storage backend. This backend uses a file on the host where it creates a logical volume from which it exposes a loop device to the docker containers.

This is why all IO is going through this process.

More info about loopback [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/daemon/graphdriver/devmapper/README.md)